# ReactJS API calls to Django REST - use IP or localhost?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, windows-server-2019

I run a ReactJS front end application and Django REST back end/API both on the same webhost. The application works perfectly fine on localhost, however when you run it from somewhere else it can't seem to connect to the API.

Console of client's browser:

[image]

Django REST running on the server:

[image]

Am I supposed to connect to it using the external IP of the server instead of localhost? Localhost should work right, since both the frontend and Django API are hosted on the same server?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 should work, localhost only if it is mapped in hosts and external IP would not

Comment: @iklinac Any clue why I'm getting the connection refused error then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone is looking for an answer, I've learned a few things since posting:

- The Django API has to be accessed by the IP, not localhost.
- Since my website is on HTTPS, Django has to be accessed by HTTPS as well or it won't work.
- Since Django runserver doesn't support HTTPS you need to host it with a webserver (you should do this anyway in production), I used Apache for this.

Thanks to xxnora for giving me tips and steering me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

before fetch the django rest_api, make sure you setup `django-cors-headers` in your backend `settings.py`. for more information take a look at this [link](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/).

`pip install django-cors-headers`

settings.py :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]
```

```
MIDDLEWARE = [  # Or MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES on Django < 1.10
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

```
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]
```

Comment: did you setup your default port `8000` in your `securtiy-group` on your server ?

Comment: Either run your django project as `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: I tried running it as 0.0.0.0:8000, it does connect but then it gives the cors error that you cannot access HTTP (django) from HTTPS (front end website)

Comment: Add the all the above things in your `settings.py` which i answered in this post. last thing is either allow `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` or `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://localhost:3000"
]`

Comment: I just added all the things you mentioned. When I access the API by domain it gives me ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, when I access it by localhost:8000 it gives me ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and by 0.0.0.0:8000 it gives me ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID. I'm so confused, let's settle this first how am I supposed to access the API? Domain, localhost or 0.0.0.0? Django is hosted on 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: It's too much confusing... do you use any remote desktop application? for view your code in live.

Comment: Yes I do, and yes it's confusing for me too! :) Can I add you somewhere to chat? Skype, discord?

Comment: sent you a request (simon)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220573/discussion-between-sj19-and-xxnora).

Answer (score 0):

you can use your public ip adress, to do so, you have to add your public ip adress in your `settings.py` file in your django project like this :

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['your-public-ip-adress', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']` replace `'your-public-ip-adress'` with your real public ip

If you don't know how to check your public ip adress, check it out on this site https://www.whatismyip.com/

You will need to run your django project like this `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` so that it can be accessible externally

By following these steps, your django apis will be accessible externally.
Make sure you replace this `http://127.0.0.1:8000` with your public ip adress in the endpoint on your client side ( in react in your case )

Hope this helps, Thank you